# Avro schema doesn't honor backward compatibilty

Tags: java, serialization, avro

I have this avro schema

```
{
 "namespace": "xx.xxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx",
 "type": "record",
 "name": "MyPayLoad",
 "fields": [
     {"name": "filed1",  "type": "string"},
     {"name": "filed2",     "type": "long"},
     {"name": "filed3",  "type": "boolean"},
     {
          "name" : "metrics",
          "type": 
          {
             "type" : "array", 
             "items": 
             { 
                 "name": "MyRecord", 
                 "type": "record", 
                 "fields" : 
                     [                         
                       {"name": "min", "type": "long"}, 
                       {"name": "max", "type": "long"}, 
                       {"name": "sum", "type": "long"}, 
                       {"name": "count", "type": "long"}
                     ]
             } 
          }
     }
  ]
}
```

Here is the code which we use to parse the data

```
public static final MyPayLoad parseBinaryPayload(byte[] payload) {
        DatumReader<MyPayLoad> payloadReader = new SpecificDatumReader<>(MyPayLoad.class);
        Decoder decoder = DecoderFactory.get().binaryDecoder(payload, null);
        MyPayLoad myPayLoad = null;
        try {
            myPayLoad = payloadReader.read(null, decoder);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage(), e);
        }

        return myPayLoad;
    }
```

Now i want to add one more field int the schema so the schema looks like below

```
 {
 "namespace": "xx.xxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx",
 "type": "record",
 "name": "MyPayLoad",
 "fields": [
     {"name": "filed1",  "type": "string"},
     {"name": "filed2",     "type": "long"},
     {"name": "filed3",  "type": "boolean"},
     {
          "name" : "metrics",
          "type": 
          {
             "type" : "array", 
             "items": 
             { 
                 "name": "MyRecord", 
                 "type": "record", 
                 "fields" : 
                     [                         
                       {"name": "min", "type": "long"}, 
                       {"name": "max", "type": "long"}, 
                       {"name": "sum", "type": "long"}, 
                       {"name": "count", "type": "long"}
                     ]
             } 
          }
     }
     {"name": "agentType",  "type": ["null", "string"], "default": "APP_AGENT"}
  ]
}
```

Note the filed added and also the default is defined. The problem is that if we receive the data which was written using the older schema i get this error

```
java.io.EOFException: null
    at org.apache.avro.io.BinaryDecoder.ensureBounds(BinaryDecoder.java:473) ~[avro-1.7.4.jar:1.7.4]
    at org.apache.avro.io.BinaryDecoder.readInt(BinaryDecoder.java:128) ~[avro-1.7.4.jar:1.7.4]
    at org.apache.avro.io.BinaryDecoder.readIndex(BinaryDecoder.java:423) ~[avro-1.7.4.jar:1.7.4]
    at org.apache.avro.io.ResolvingDecoder.doAction(ResolvingDecoder.java:229) ~[avro-1.7.4.jar:1.7.4]
    at org.apache.avro.io.parsing.Parser.advance(Parser.java:88) ~[avro-1.7.4.jar:1.7.4]
    at org.apache.avro.io.ResolvingDecoder.readIndex(ResolvingDecoder.java:206) ~[avro-1.7.4.jar:1.7.4]
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:152) ~[avro-1.7.4.jar:1.7.4]
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readRecord(GenericDatumReader.java:177) ~[avro-1.7.4.jar:1.7.4]
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:148) ~[avro-1.7.4.jar:1.7.4]
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:139) ~[avro-1.7.4.jar:1.7.4]
    at com.appdynamics.blitz.shared.util.XXXXXXXXXXXXX.parseBinaryPayload(BlitzAvroSharedUtil.java:38) ~[blitz-shared.jar:na]
```

What i understood from [this](https://martin.kleppmann.com/2012/12/05/schema-evolution-in-avro-protocol-buffers-thrift.html) document that this should have been backward compatible but somehow that doesn't seem to be the case. Any idea what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

finally i got this working. I need to give both the schemas in the SpecificDatumReader
So i modified the parsing like this where i passed both the old and new schema in the reader and it worked like a charm

```
public static final MyPayLoad parseBinaryPayload(byte[] payload) {
        DatumReader<MyPayLoad> payloadReader = new SpecificDatumReader<>(SCHEMA_V1, SCHEMA_V2);
        Decoder decoder = DecoderFactory.get().binaryDecoder(payload, null);
        MyPayLoad myPayLoad = null;
        try {
            myPayLoad = payloadReader.read(null, decoder);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage(), e);
        }

        return myPayLoad;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible issues that i can see in your schema

1. The default value for me always seems to have work as null
   to specify this you need to set

`"default": null`

2. Also in your schema you did forget to add a , (field separator) between the array and new field. Hence try changing your schema as

`{
 "namespace": "xx.xxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx",
 "type": "record",
 "name": "MyPayLoad",
 "fields": [
     {"name": "filed1",  "type": "string"},
     {"name": "filed2",     "type": "long"},
     {"name": "filed3",  "type": "boolean"},
     {
          "name" : "metrics",
          "type":
          {
             "type" : "array",
             "items":
             {
                 "name": "MyRecord",
                 "type": "record",
                 "fields" :
                     [
                       {"name": "min", "type": "long"},
                       {"name": "max", "type": "long"},
                       {"name": "sum", "type": "long"},
                       {"name": "count", "type": "long"}
                     ]
             }
          }
     },
     {"name": "agentType",  "type": ["null", "string"], "default":null}
  ]
}`

Answer (score 0):

I am facing this exact situation. Data written by the older schema fails when trying to read it with the newer schema. The newer schema has just one additional field with union and default set. 
"type":["null","string"],"doc":"","default":null

In spite of setting default, the null doesn't get filled in automatically during reading. Both the writer and the reader schemas need to be provided during reading. My understanding was avro is backward compatible and it should be able to support newer columns without the need for the older schema.