# Avro doesn't provide backward compatibility

Tags: java, avro, backwards-compatibility

I need to send my data through stream, So I chose Avro for data serialization and deserialization. But the existing implementation using avro readers, doesn't support backward compatibility. Write serialized data into file and read from file support backward compatibility. How can I achieve backward compatibility, without knowing the writer's schema. I found many stackoverflow questions related to this. But I didn't find any solution for this issue. Can someone help me to solve this.

Following is my serializer and deserializer methods.

```
   public static byte[] serialize(String json, Schema schema) throws IOException {
        GenericDatumWriter<Object> writer = new GenericDatumWriter<>(schema);
        ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Encoder encoder = EncoderFactory.get().binaryEncoder(output, null);
        DatumReader<Object> reader = new GenericDatumReader<>(schema);
        Decoder decoder = DecoderFactory.get().jsonDecoder(schema, json);
        Object datum = reader.read(null, decoder);
        writer.write(datum, encoder);
        encoder.flush();
        output.flush();
        return output.toByteArray();

}

    public static String deserialize(byte[] avro, Schema schema) throws IOException {
        GenericDatumReader<Object> reader = new GenericDatumReader(schema);
        Decoder decoder = DecoderFactory.get().binaryDecoder(avro, null);
        Object datum = reader.read(null, decoder);
        ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        JsonEncoder encoder = EncoderFactory.get().jsonEncoder(schema, output);

        DatumWriter<Object> writer = new GenericDatumWriter(schema);
        writer.write(datum, encoder);
        encoder.flush();
        output.flush();
        return new String(output.toByteArray(), "UTF-8");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You may have to define what scope you are looking for backward compatibility. Are you expecting new attributes to be added? OR are you going to remove any attributes? To handle both of these scenarios, there are different options available.

As described on the [confluent blog](https://docs.confluent.io/current/avro.html#backward-compatibility), addition of new attributes can be achieved and avro serialization/deserialization activity can be made backward compatible, you must specify `default` value for the new attribute. Something like below

```
{"name": "size", "type": "string", "default": "XL"}
```

The other option is to specify, [reader and writer schemas exclusively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34733604/avro-schema-doesnt-honor-backward-compatibilty). But as described in your question, it doesn't seems to be an option you are looking for.

If you are planning to remove an attribute, you can continue to parse the attribute but don't use it in application. Note this has to happen for a definite period and consumers must be given enough time to make changes to their program, before you completely retire the attribute. Make sure to log a statement to indicate the attribute was found when it was not supposed to be sent (or better send a notification to client system with a warning).

Besides above points, there is an excellent blog which talks about [backward/forward compatibility](http://dekarlab.de/wp/?p=489).

Comment: I already specified default value. I got java.io.EOFException while running the code.

Comment: I experienced the same issue even I have default. Did you finally get it working ?

Answer (score 0):

Backward compatibility means that you can encode data with an older schema and the data can still be decoded by a reader that knows the latest schema.

[Explanation from Confluent's website](https://docs.confluent.io/current/avro.html#backward-compatibility)

So in order to decode Avro data with backward compatibility, your reader needs access to the latest schema. This can be done for example using a Schema Registry.