# Adding new fields into Avro Schema got compatibility exception

Tags: java, apache-kafka, schema, avro

I have a simple avro schema and I added one new field into avro schema by providing default value like this:

```
{
    "name": "channelType",
    "type": [
        "null",
        {
            "type": "string",
            "avro.java.string": "String"
        }
    ],
    "default": null
},
```

Used the following code to deserialize data.

```
public class RLoggerKafkaMessageDeSerializer implements Deserializer<RLoggerMessage> {
    private final DecoderFactory decoderFactory = DecoderFactory.get();
    private final DatumReader<RLoggerMessage> reader;

    public RLoggerKafkaMessageDeSerializer() {
        super();
        reader = new SpecificDatumReader<RLoggerMessage>(RLoggerMessage.getClassSchema());
    }

    @Override
    public RLoggerMessage deserialize(final String topic, final byte[] data) {
        try {
            BinaryDecoder decoder = decoderFactory.binaryDecoder(data, null);
            RLoggerMessage rlogMessage = reader.read(null, decoder);

            return rlogMessage;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new SerializationException("Error deserialize message", e);
        } 
    }
}
```

Then I got the following errors:

```
java.io.EOFException
at org.apache.avro.io.BinaryDecoder.ensureBounds(BinaryDecoder.java:473)
at org.apache.avro.io.BinaryDecoder.readInt(BinaryDecoder.java:128)
at org.apache.avro.io.BinaryDecoder.readIndex(BinaryDecoder.java:423)
at org.apache.avro.io.ResolvingDecoder.doAction(ResolvingDecoder.java:290)
at org.apache.avro.io.parsing.Parser.advance(Parser.java:88)
at org.apache.avro.io.ResolvingDecoder.readIndex(ResolvingDecoder.java:267)
at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion(GenericDatumReader.java:178)
at org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumReader.readField(SpecificDatumReader.java:116)
at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readRecord(GenericDatumReader.java:230)
at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion(GenericDatumReader.java:174)
at org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumReader.readField(SpecificDatumReader.java:116)
at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readRecord(GenericDatumReader.java:230)
at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion(GenericDatumReader.java:174)
at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:152)
at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:144)
```

Notes: I found one solution which is to add both old schema and new schema into SpecificDatumReader. Refer to this link: [Avro schema doesn't honor backward compatibilty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34733604/avro-schema-doesnt-honor-backward-compatibilty).
This solution is not working for me. Our team is using schema Registry. I already uploaded the new schema to schema Registry. I understanding is the latest schema should be picked up to serialize/deserialize the data. However, the exception above appeared.

Comment: If you're using Schema Registry, why are you writing your own deserializer? The schema is not part of the message in that case

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks for the comment. Can you explain more? I cannot get your point.